# javax.websocket dependency usage

Tags: java, eclipse, websocket

Hi all I am working around with Web Sockets where I have to import **javax.websocket** dependency. I have downloaded from
https://jar-download.com/artifacts/javax.websocket
and added the jar to my project code is clean and without errors. Here is my code

Server code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.websocket.ClientEndpoint;
import javax.websocket.OnError;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;

public class Server {
@OnOpen
public void onOpen(Session session) {
    System.out.println("Connected to endpoint: " + session.getBasicRemote());
    try {
        String name = "Duke";
        System.out.println("Sending message to endpoint: " + name);
        session.getBasicRemote().sendText(name);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

@OnMessage
public void processMessage(String message) {
    System.out.println("Received message in client: " + message);
    Client.messageLatch.countDown();
}

@OnError
public void processError(Throwable t) {
    t.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Client code :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.websocket.ContainerProvider;
import javax.websocket.DeploymentException;
import javax.websocket.WebSocketContainer;


public class Client {

final static CountDownLatch messageLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        WebSocketContainer container = ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer();
        String uri = "ws://echo.websocket.org:80/";
        System.out.println("Connecting to " + uri);
        container.connectToServer(Client.class, URI.create(uri));
        messageLatch.await(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (DeploymentException | InterruptedException | IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
  }
}
```

My problem is when am running the server i am getting the following error :

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find an implementation class.
at javax.websocket.ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer(ContainerProvider.java:73)
at test.Client.main(Client.java:80)**

Up to my knowledge the error is saying that ContainerProvider. But the same classes is present in the  jar I have imported in my project.

Please correct me or suggest me where I am going wrong. By the way I am following this git hub project.

**https://github.com/koekiebox/javaee7-samples/tree/master/websocket/javase-client/src/main/java/org/javaee7/websocket/javase/client**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's an exception from ContainerProvider, not about ContainerProvider.

Comment: oh ok thanks for the reply, can you help me with why I am getting the exception, I mean am I doing the implementation in wrong way or something ?

Comment: There's a lot here. Why are you working from code in a fork that's that far behind the original? How do you have an exception from line 80 when the code you've shown has far fewer lines? Are you not using the provided `pom.xml` file to find the libraries it needs?

Comment: I have some commented lines before the code so the line number is different